# How do I find an unnamed iframe with Capybara

Tags: html, ruby, iframe, cucumber, capybara

The iframe I am trying to access is 3 iframes deep, and vague to boot

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" src="javascript:void(0)"></iframe>
```

No ID, name or value.

can I just do ...

```
within_frame(iframe)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Capybara::Selenium::Driver.within_frame](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb#L77) passes `frame_id` to webdriver:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(frame_id)
```

Webdriver's [frame](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/TargetLocator.html#frame-instance_method) method invokes [switchToFrame](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Remote/Bridge.html#switchToFrame-instance_method) method that accepts [index, name or id](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html)

So to access 3 iframes deep iframe you can do:

```
within_frame 0 do
  within_frame 0 do
    within_frame 0 do
      # do something
    end
  end
end
```