# Unable to locate unnamed iframes in capybara using the 0 index

Tags: ruby, iframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I have an iframe that is unnamed so I'm trying to use the solution here to access it: [How do I find an unnamed I-Frame with Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096661/how-do-i-find-an-unnamed-i-frame-with-capybara?rq=1) but I continue to get the following error: Unable to locate frame: 0 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchFrameError)

The frame of interest is two frames deep so I have set up the code below but it fails with the aforementioned error; I also took a look into the source of the driver but the section I'm interested in that references the index is commented out: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb could this mean that it has been deprecated?

```
require "capybara/dsl"

include Capybara::DSL

Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.default_selector = :xpath
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false

visit "http://example.com"

within_frame 0 do
  within_frame 0 do
    imagelist = page.all("//div[contains(@class, 'panel')]//img")
    chosenimages = imagelist.map{ |link| link['src'] }
    imagechoices = chosenimages.map do |imagechoice|
    finalfilename = File.basename(imagechoice)
    puts finalfilename
    puts imagechoice
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out I actually was using the wrong index for the first within_frame the page in question had some hidden frames that I didn't take into account. +1 capybara and +1 stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line to switch into frame.

`switch_to.frame(index)`